# Uniform continuity implies continuity in topological vector spaces

Tags: general-topology, continuity, uniform-continuity, filters

Let $E$ and $F$ be topological vector spaces and $A \subset E$. I want to prove that: if $f: A \longrightarrow F$ is a uniformly continuous function, then $f$ is continuous.

I want that, by definition of uniformly continuous we have for all $V \in \mathcal{F}(0_F)$ there exists $U \in  \mathcal{F}(0_E)$ such that if $x_1,x_2 \in A$ and $x_1-x_2 \in U$ implies
$$f(x_1)-f(x_2) \in V$$
where $0_E$ and $0_F$ denote the origin of $E$ and $F$ respectively. Moreover $ \mathcal{F}(0_E)$ and $ \mathcal{F}(0_F)$ are the filters of neighborhoods of the origins.

But, I am not able to tie these facts with continuity, since the definition of continuity is via $f$ inverse images.

Comment: This should be analogous to the proof from real analysis.

Comment: It may be, but it is not clear to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix $x\in A$ and let $V$ be an open set around $f(x)$. Then $-f(x)+V\in\mathcal{F}(0_F)$, so there exists $U\in\mathcal{F}(0_E)$ such that $x_1,x_2\in A$ with $x_1-x_2\in U$ implies $f(x_1)-f(x_2)\in -f(x)+V$. Consequently, $(x+U)\cap A$ is an open set in $A$ containing $x$ such that $f((x+U)\cap A)\subset V$, so $f$ is continuous at $x$ for all $x\in A$.

Edit: For clarity, the notion of continuity I used here is that a function between topological spaces $f:X\to Y$ is continuous if and only if for every $x\in X$ and every open set $V$ in $Y$ containing $f(x)$, there exists an open set $U$ in $X$ containing $x$ such that $f(U)\subset V$. It is a standard exercise in topology that this is equivalent to other definitions of continuous.

Comment: Why $f((x+U) \cap A) \subset V$?

Comment: It's because $f(x_1)-f(x_2)+f(x) \in V$?

Comment: I wanted to leave that for you to verify instead of giving you all the details myself. Let $y\in f((x+U)\cap A)$ so that $y=f(x')$ for some $x'\in (x+U)\cap A$. Use the previously stated property of $U$ to show that $y\in V$.